# Azure Batch Task problem executing a VBS file

Tags: azure, batch-processing, azure-batch

I'm trying to launch a VBS file as an Azure Batch Task and I'm constantly getting errors that the script file cannot be found.

Here's one command that works:

```
string appPath = String.Format("%AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_{0}#{1}%", appPackageId, appPackageVersion);
string taskCommandLine = String.Format("cmd /c {0}\\ffmpeg-3.4-win64-static\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i {1} -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 128k {2} & del {3} & rename {4} {5}", appPath, inputMediaFile, outputMediaFile, inputMediaFile, outputMediaFile, inputMediaFile);
```

This one works correctly, but before firing ffmpeg on the input file, I'd like to do some checks with ffprobe first and doing so with a .bat kind of sucks so I tought of doing it in VBScript.

```
string appPath = String.Format("%AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_{0}#{1}%", appPackageId, appPackageVersion);
string taskCommandLine = String.Format("cmd /c cscript {0}\\ffmpeg-3.4-win64-static\\bin\\scan_run1.vbs {1} {2}", appPath, inputMediaFile, outputMediaFile);
```

Which results in:

> Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8 Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Input Error: Can not find script file
>   "D:\batch\tasks\applications\ffmpeg3.42019-02-01-19-50\ffmpeg-3.4-win64-static\bin\scan_run1.vbs"

I'm pretty sure the vbs is there, because invoking ffmpeg.exe at the exact same location works fine.

Is the Azure Portal stripping out the VBS out of the ZIP file when I upload it as package ? What is going on there ?

Thanks.

---

Turns out Azure Portal is not updating the application package when I replace it. So it's got "scan_run.vbs" but not "scan_run1.vbs" even though the ZIP file on my end has it.

Comment: I think there is something else, so your task has a package and you updated used it with *.bat and it worked and then once you updated the package with new files == **1)** did you re-uploaded the package? **2)** did you re-ran it as another task or same task? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages There are various nitty gritty of how the Environment variables get set etc, with it. App packages are Pool level or task level and in your case the scenario is task level.

Comment: Continue... If you use tools like `batch-explorer` you will be able to dig under the fold structure in your node and see if the file exist. To me this is the clear case of some `user error` category, have you tried with version number? did it worked with version number? **Please note** `If a specified package and version is already installed on the node, the package is not downloaded and the existing package is used.` please let me know how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: *Further*: This has nothing to do with what you see locally in zip, when you update the package which was existing with new content and try it in the existing node then it all depends on the node level mechanism, i.e. if you have different version of packages, please refer to the link I shared. Firstly, try with version and package, secondly if you are altering the same package too frequently then design wise I would recommend utilizing the app version feature, thirdly in case you want to update the same package you need to make sure task has a backing mechanism in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will help in better understanding, essentially the short answer is this:

Reference from document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages

> Similar to a pool, you specify application package references for a
>   task. When a task is scheduled to run on a node, the package is
>   downloaded and extracted just before the task's command line is
>   executed. **If a specified package and version is already installed on
>   the node, the package is not downloaded and the existing package is
>   used**.

**Detail**

Like I mentioned in the comments, if you have different version of application package it is recommended.

This is great that you are exploring these errors because this will help in better design of this concept around your application.

**recommendations**

- For example: `If you have all tasks sharing same application package, I would recommend using Pool Level app pkgs` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages#install-pool-application-packages
- `If you have task level and you are changing the content of existing app pkgs` then use the app pks with version and make version different with different content of app pkgs.

How version works is detailed here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages#execute-the-installed-applications

Extras:

- Little bit in detail as to how many environment variables and types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-compute-node-environment-variables
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages#benefits-of-application-packages

**Common Gotchas**

- If user app is uplaoding app pkgs on the fly via API, or manually, make sure the package is correctly uploaded, *Programmaticvally* usually `non async` behaviour leads to an issue, so always wait for the uplaod to finish before Batch creates a pool and proceeds.

Comment: All my tasks indeed use the same packages, but I've found that using the package at the task level makes it that the task always has the up to date package contents. Is there any reason not do it this way ?

Comment: @FrancisDucharme Thats correct, good that you are thinking of user scenario now, **Question** `Since all your task need that same App package, why Pool scenario is not fitting your use case? ` is it because you have applicaiton pacakge constantly changing? also how you are uploading your packages?

Comment: Testing purposes for the moment, so the content changes often but once it's stable, I guess I could use it at pool level. I'm uploading it with Batch Explorer (desktop app)

Comment: @FrancisDucharme Saweet, sounds good, so its just for POC (Proof of concept), then I think that looks cool, as long as if you follow the pool level approach if the package is same for all. For your current POC approach for changing often Task level App pkgs, then make sure you are uploading the new version with `unique app id and version` for the tasks to pickup, also be aware of these **MAX** https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-quota-limit#other-limits  I hope this gives you better idea for your solution design `:)` Also you need to make sure pkgs are uploaded before task runs